Action of charge conjugation on bispinors
I'm following an introductory course to particle physics. We have introduced Klein-Gordon's equation for spinless particles and Dirac's equation for spin $1/2$ particles. Klein-Gordon's equation works with the usual wavefunctions $\Psi(\vec r)$. Dirac's equation works with bispinors meaning it describes the behaviour of a particle-antiparticle pair with four wavefunctions: the first two relating to the particle $a$ and the remaining two describing the antiparticle $\bar a$.
$$
\Psi_{a\bar a}(\vec r_1, \vec r_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
   \Psi_{a\uparrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{a\downarrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{\bar a\uparrow}(\vec r_2) \\
   \Psi_{\bar a\downarrow}(\vec r_2) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Following Martin Shaw's book (4th edition, section 1.3.2), the professor gave a definition of the charge conjugation operator $\hat C$ using Dirac's ket notation. We said that if $a = \bar a$ while $b \neq \bar b$ then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\hat C \vert{a}\rangle = \vert{\bar a}\rangle = \pm \vert{a}\rangle, \\
&\hat C \vert{b}\rangle = \vert{\bar b}\rangle, \\
&\hat C \vert{b\bar b}\rangle = \pm\vert{b\bar b}\rangle. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
This is a rather unclear definition of $\hat C$ since we have not mathematically specified the meaning of this kets.
The question: Is it possible to define the action of $\hat C$ on individual wavefunctions for spin zero particles? Can we do the same with bispinors in the context of spin 1/2 particles?
My guess: I'm guessing
$$
\hat C\begin{pmatrix}
   \Psi_{a\uparrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{a\downarrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{\bar a\uparrow}(\vec r_2) \\
   \Psi_{\bar a\downarrow}(\vec r_2) \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
   \Psi_{\bar a\uparrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{\bar a\downarrow}(\vec r_1) \\
   \Psi_{a\uparrow}(\vec r_2) \\
   \Psi_{a\downarrow}(\vec r_2) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I'm not sure.
